# Opencart - Display only the subcategories of the current category

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using `OpenCart 2` and I want to modify the default category module to show me only the subcategories of the current category up to a level 3.

For example, if I am on the “Laptops & Desktops” category page, the sidebar module would only list the sub-categories associated with “Laptops & Desktops” category, such as “Macs” and “PCs” with the main heading “Laptops & Desktops” (And not list or show any of the other top level categories). In addition to that I want it to show the subcategories of "Macs" and "PCs" too.

**Laptops & Desktops**

-- ***Macs***

---- Subcategory 1

-- ***PCs***

---- Subcategory 1

---- Subcategory 2

If I go to category PCs I will see:

**PCs**

-- Subcategory 1

-- Subcategory 2

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Download “Show only subcategories on category page OpenCart 2.0 free module” from link below:
[Download Show Only SubCategories](https://webocreation.com/blog/show-only-subcategories-on-category-page-opencart-2-0-free-module)

Please download as per version. There is one version for 2.2 and another version for 2.0

Comment: Yes but I need subcategories up to a level 3 or 4

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I make it run at least up to level 3?

Answer (score 0):

You need into change core file
catalog → controller → module → category.php

replace

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
```

with following

```
> $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']); 
> $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);
> $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);
```

Comment: Does not work. If I put the code above it displays nothing but the module title.

Comment: Andrei, May i know the website URL where you can tried to apply this code?

Comment: http://edelweiss-shop.ro/imbracaminte-munte/Imbracaminte-Barbati/jachete-pentru-barbati
But now I removed the categories sidebar.